# Find basis and dimension of $L^{\bot} $ if $L$ is given

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

I have to find basis and dimension of $L^{\bot}$ if linear subspace $L=\langle\mathbf{a}_1,\mathbf{a}_2,\mathbf{a}_3 \rangle$ where:

$\mathbf{a}_1=(1,0,1,-1) \\ \mathbf{a}_2=(2,1,0,-1)\\ \mathbf{a}_3=(1,1,2,-3)$

Thoughts:

write down the matrix and apply gaussian elimination

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&-1\\2&1&0&-1\\1&1&2&-3 \end{pmatrix} \sim \begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&-1\\0&1&-2&1\\0&0&1&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

so $\mathrm{rank}A=\dim{A}=3$ and $\langle a_1,a_2,a_3 \rangle$ is basis cause ther's no linear-dependent vectors.

Am I right?

Comment: yes, its right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have proved that $L$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ of dimension $3$, because it is the span of the three linearly independent vectors $\mathbf a_1,\mathbf a_2,\mathbf a_3$.

So its orthogonal complement $L^\bot$ has dimension $1$ and any vector orthogonal to the three $\mathbf a_1,\mathbf a_2,\mathbf a_3$ is  a basis for $T^\bot$.

You can find such a vector simply writing that it is orthogonal to any linear combination of $\mathbf a_1,\mathbf a_2,\mathbf a_3$.

Comment: hmm. how did you find demension of $L^{\bot}=1$? I thought it matches rank of tha matrix

Comment: For the vector space $\mathbb{R}^4$, with the usual inner product, we have $dim (L) + dim (L^\bot)=dim \mathbb{R}^4$.

Answer (score 0):

Here, $L^\perp=\DeclareMathOperator{Null}{Null}\Null(A)$ where 
$$
A=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
2 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & -3
\end{array}\right]
$$
Row-reducing shows that 
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref(A)
=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1
\end{array}\right]
$$
It follows that $\vec x=\langle x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\rangle$ is in the null space of $A$ if and only if
$$
\left[\begin{array}{r}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3} \\
x_{4}
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{r}
0 \\
x_{4} \\
x_{4} \\
x_{4}
\end{array}\right]
=
x_4
\left[\begin{array}{r}
0 \\
1\\
1\\
1\\
\end{array}\right]
$$
This shows that
$$
L^\perp=\Null(A)=\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span\left\{\left[\begin{array}{r}
0 \\
1\\
1\\
1\\
\end{array}\right]\right\}
$$